# rails find first object and show it's property

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this code.

```
<%=  Article.find do |a| %>
<a href='<%= a.link %>'  '>Our reviews</a>
<% end %>
```

What I want to actually do is just to find the first Article(or last - don't really care its property link has the same value ) and show it's property link.
But my code gives me strange effect and after my link I have something like this:

```
#<Article:0x9c1e004>
```

You can see that on the screenshot after review link in the left menu there is this stuff. How do I remove it?
[image]

Comment: You need to just remove `=` in this line `<%=  Article.find do |a| %>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
<% a = Article.first %>
```

You don't need a block (do ... end) for that

to remove `#<Article:0x9c1e004>` you should remove the `=` like Pavan commented in `<%=  Article.find do |a| %>`

Comment: what does this = do?

Comment: with the = it'll print to the view, without it it will compute but not render to the view.